# Output polygon is the inverse of what I need?

Tags: python, polygon, rasterio, polygon-creation

I am trying to output a different polygons from a single band GeoTIFF. I am trying output different polygons for specific range values such as 0.4 <= x < 0.5, 0.5 <= x < 0.6 etc (each value is within the range 0-1). However, when I run it using the following code it created a GeoJSON file that I can put into QGIS, but for some reason it's creating the inverse polygon of what I want (a polygon is created using all the values I set to 0 within the first `for` loop, even if I switch this around and make the others 0 the same polygon is created). Any suggestions of how to get the inverse polygon of the one that is being produced?

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp
import json
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open('tifs/example1.tiff') as dataset:

    mask = dataset.dataset_mask()
    print("Mask = ", mask)

    #This contains the values that need to be tested i.e x > 0 AND x < 0.1
    full_image = dataset.read()

    for x in np.nditer(full_image, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if (x >= 0.2 and x < 0.3):
            x[...] = 0
        else:
            x[...] = 1

    # for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(full_image, connectivity=4, transform=dataset.transform):
    #     geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)

    geoms = []
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(full_image, connectivity=4, transform=dataset.transform):
        print("val = ", val)
        if val != 1:
            continue
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)
        geoms.append(geom)

    with open('pointTwoToPointThree.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(geoms, f)
    print(geoms)
```

Answer (score 2):

`shapes()` returns a polygon for each value in the array, including `0`.

And this loop

```
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(full_image, connectivity=4, transform=dataset.transform):
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)
```

is always leaving `geom` set to the last feature that `shapes()` happens to return, so that's what ends up getting written out.

Check `val` in that loop to only retain geometries with the value you're interested in.  And you should probably account for multiple polygons with the target value.

```
    geoms = []
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(full_image, connectivity=4, transform=dataset.transform):
        if val != 1:
            continue
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)
        geoms.append(geom)
```

Comment: The same problem still occurs. I've debugged and the full_image variable shows the values in the range as 1 and all others as 0. However, the output polygon is all of the 0 values??

Comment: Can you edit your post with the most recent version of your code?

Comment: Due to the new json output being a list I have to simply go in for the time being and remove the [] but it's now giving me a tiny polygon outside of the original coordinate area??